# LUA ERROR running the app on android

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm a new programmer with no much experience; as a good noob it's very probable that the next code lines you will see may show a wide number of errors or imprecisions thus I'm excusing myself ahead of time.
So, the situation is the following:
Lately I'm interfacing with a new programming language (new for me obviously) that is LUA (using corona sdk). I approached the language writing simple codes.
Now I'm trying to execute a program that has simply to display two rectangles affected by the gravity. When I try to emulate the applicarion on my PC with CORONA it works without any kind of problem; after having built it for android OS, having installed it on my phone and having run it the result is an error message that is the following:

This is the error message:

"main.lua.35: ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call you might have used '.' instead of ':' "

This is the code:

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local _W = display.contentWidth
local _H = display.contentHeight

local platform = display.newRect(
    --x =
     _W/2,
    --y = 
     _H/2,
    --width = 
     100,
    --height = 
     100
)

platform.surfaceType = "rectangle"  

local myImage = display.newImage("icon.png",_W/2,50)

local iconCollision = {
    friction = 0.0, --attrito
    bounce = 0.0, --rimbalzo (forse)
    isSensor = true --collisione con altri oggetti
}

physics.addBody(platform,"static") 
physics.addBody(myImage,"dynamic",iconCollision) --this is line 35

platform.collision = onCollision

local function onGyroscopeDataReceived( event )
    local deltaRadians = event.zRotation * event.deltaTime
    local deltaDegrees = deltaRadians * (180/math.pi)
end

local function dragImage(event)
    local t=event.target
    print(event.phase)
    if(event.phase == "moved") then 
        t.x = event.x
        t.y = event.y
    end
end

local function onCollision( event )
        if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
            print("toccato")
        end
end

if system.hasEventSource( "gyroscope" ) then
    Runtime:addEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
end

Runtime:addEventListener("collision",onCollision)
myImage:addEventListener("touch",dragImage)
```

I will be very grateful with those who will try to help me.

Comment: The error message explains it completely. It says it was expecting a table as a function argument (the first argument, actually) and it suggests to replace `.` with `:`. This is because `tab:func(arg1, arg2)` is a shortcut for `tab.func(tab, arg1, arg2)`. The program automatically inserts the table as the first argument of the function.

Comment: Try calling `physics:addBody(platform, "static")` and `physics:addBody(myImage, "dynamic", iconCollision)` or even `physics.addBody(phisycs, platform,"static")` and `physics.addBody(physics, myImage,"dynamic",iconCollision)` and it should work.

Comment: Line `platform.collision = onCollision` must be AFTER body of function `onCollision`

Comment: Second argument of `addEventListener` must be an object inside which a function was defined (not a function itself).  See [docs and examples](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventListener/addEventListener.html).  You cannot use stand-alone function such as `onCollision` and `dragImage`.  These functions must have `self` as their first argument: `onCollision(self, event)`.  You mast specify an object which contains this function, for example: `Runtime:addEventListener("collision", platform)`

Comment: BTW, your line 35 is completely correct.  You can send a bugreport to Corona team: error message incorrectly points to a line which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe  `event.zRotation` is `null`. On iOS, you can use the appropriate `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. In `building.settings` add this `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities = { ["gyroscope"]=true }`. On Android set the `usesFeatures = { { name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope", required=true } }`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the name of the image on the disk , "icon.png", uppercase and lowercase matters, on Android device it could lead to errors, not showed in simulators.
If it doesn't load myImage:addEventListener would display an errore, maybe the one you see.
Also try to exclude pieces of code and then run the program on device back. I found difference with simulator that way.